# visual studio sloution file for a website and root is not as i want it

Tags: visual-studio

okay...im really puzzled with this.

I want to create a regular asp.net webforms website (nota web application project). i also want a solution file associated with the website which when double-clicked opens visual studio with the website loaded in solution explorer.

i did this by creating a blank solution "project"
then adding new website to this.

however the problem is when i hit debug, the page loads up at http://localhost:2118/temp/Default.aspx
i want it to just be http://localhost:2118/Default.aspx

how can i do this??

also related to this, what is the standard stucture of a website with a .sln solution file.
should the solution file exist in the same dir as web.config?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
Open Site Properties, "Web" tab.
Then, select following options:
Radio "Use VS Development Server"
Radio "Specific port" - 2118
Texbox "Virtual Path" = "/"

SLN file should be upper one level:

SolutionNameFolder
-slnfile
-WebSiteNameFolder
--web.config
--website contents

Comment: found it thanks. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/19/tip-trick-how-to-run-a-root-site-with-the-local-web-server-using-vs-2005-sp1.aspx

Comment: Sorry, forgot the "Site" word :)